# Documenting where stored procs are called from

Tags: sql-server-2012

I've been wishing lately that we documented what all places stored procedures are called from. It would have to be pretty painless to do though... i.e. doing it in excel wouldn't be very good.

Seems like this might be a common desire (probably even a requirement for some companies) so I'm wondering if there are any tools/applications/add ins out there already that facilitate this?

EDIT: To be clear, I'm not really looking for tools that help me identify what needs to be documented (although I would still love to hear about any you think I may be unaware of), but rather a tool that helps me do the documenting.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has the [sys.sql_dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) table.

In SSMS you can right-click an object and choose "dependencies". My subjective experience is that this can be incomplete.

References from application code may be amenable to a simple search, depending on how it's constructed.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion though I'm aware of that. Unfortunately the problem isn't the dependencies within SQL but rather those outside of it. In my case, primarily from .net applications and scheduled tasks. And yes, doing searches is how I generally identify whether an application uses a proc but we have several applications and it can be a pain to go through them all.

Comment: Also, as you mentioned it can be incomplete when you have cross db calls as I believe that only shows dependencies w/in the db. Nonetheless, it is still a good feature that I use quite a bit when trying to do stuff like this.

Comment: @BVernon you may want update your question with things you're aware of so the Welcoming and Inclusive® folks who answer questions around here can provide better information.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik hmm... I'm not really sure of any tools that allow me to document stored proc usage. I would have to create my own as far as I know, but this just seemed like something people have probably done for decades in some companies so I'm wondering if there are any tools that can help. That is, I don't need help identifying what needs to be documented... I'm looking for something to help me do the documenting. I guess I will clarify that though.